How do I avoid SDK and use raw fetch with Groq API?
I get a 404 on the api call. It appears to be using the deprecated API. I want to know how do a fetch/curl call with latest groq.com API. Anyone know how to fix? The official SDK is overly complex and I just want to make fetch requests.
const response = await fetch('https://api.groq.com/v1/engines/llama3/completions', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${env.GROQ_API_KEY}`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        prompt,
        // maxTokens: 150000, // Customize as needed
        temperature: 0.5, // Customize as needed
        topP: 1.0, // Customize as needed
        n: 1, // Number of completions to generate
        stop: null // Optional stopping sequence
    })
});


I get a 404 on the api call. it appears to be using the deprecated api, I want to know how do a fetch/curl call with latest groq.com api

Curl solution:
curl "https://api.groq.com/openai/v1/chat/completions" \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${GROQ_API_KEY}" \
  -d '{
         "messages": [
           {
             "role": "system",
             "content": "You are a helpful assistant"
           },
           {
             "role": "user",
             "content": "Hello"
           }
         ],
         "model": "llama3-8b-8192",
         "temperature": 1,
         "max_tokens": 1024,
         "top_p": 1,
         "stream": true,
         "stop": null
       }'

Fetch solution:
        const response = await fetch('https://api.groq.com/openai/v1/chat/completions', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${env.GROQ_API_KEY}`
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                messages: [
                    {
                        role: 'system',
                        content:
                            'You are a helpful assistant in the areas of global threat intelligence and osint. Please only return valid JSON and no other text.'
                    },
                    {
                        role: 'user',
                        content: prompt
                    }
                ],
                model: 'llama3-8b-8192',
                temperature: 1,
                // max_tokens: 1024,
                top_p: 1,
                stream: false,
                stop: null
            })
        });

        if (response.ok) {
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(data.choices[0].message?.content, '<---- groq.com api');

            return JSON.parse(data.choices[0].message?.content);
        } else {
            console.error(await response.json());
        }


2nd option working for me for now.
